# I dont understand this lifetime error : spawining threads inside a struct function

Tags: multithreading, rust, crossbeam

Not much to explain. I don't understand what is even having the lifetime designated `1 and` 2 by the compiler error message.

All posts I have checked so far just say use crossbeam for scopped threads, but this hasn't fixed my issue at all and I dont think I even understand the finer issue here.

Any help is appreciated.

```
use crossbeam_utils::thread;

struct TestStruct {
    s: f64,
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            s: -1.,
        }
    }
    fn fubar(&'static self) -> f64 {
        let thread_return_value = thread::scope(|scope|
            // lifetime may not live long enough
            // returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
            // Question: what are the two lifetimes even of? I am probably just
            // a noob here.
            scope.spawn(move |_| { // same error with or without move
                // I have found that it doesnt matter what I put in this scope,
                // but the following is the closest to what I have in my actual
                // code.
                let mut psum = 0.;
                for _ in 0..10 { psum += self.s; }
                psum
            })
        ).unwrap();
        // do anything with thread_return_value

        return 0.; // just so its explicitly not the problem here, return 0.
    }
}


fn main() {
    let test_item = TestStruct::new();
    // rustcE0597
    let stored_value = test_item.fubar();
    println!("{}", &stored_value);
    return;
}
```

Edit after marking for correct answer, working minimal example:

```
#![feature(let_chains)]
use crossbeam_utils::thread;


struct TestStruct {
    s: f64,
}

impl TestStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            s: -1.,
        }
    }

    fn fubar(&self) -> f64 {
        let thread_return_value = thread::scope(|scope| {
            let th = scope.spawn(move |_| {
                let mut psum = 0.;
                for _ in 0..10 { psum += self.s; }
                psum
            });
            let psum = th.join().unwrap();
            psum
        }
        ).unwrap();
        return thread_return_value;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let test_item = TestStruct::new();
    // rustcE0597
    let stored_value = test_item.fubar();
    println!("{}", &stored_value);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious problem in your code is the `&'static self` lifetime. If you do so, you will only be able to call this function with static (that is, global) values of this type. So just remove that `'static` and write `&self`.

Then the real problem is because you are trying to return your scoped thread handle from the `crossbeam::scoped`, the value returned by `scope.spawn()`, and that is not allowed. That is why they are called *scoped threads*: they are limited to the enclosing scope.

Remember that in Rust, when a block ends without a `;` the value of the last expression is returned as the value of the block itself.

You probably want to return the `psum`. If so you need to wait for the handle to finish:

```
    fn fubar(& self) -> f64 {
        let thread_return_value = thread::scope(|scope| {
            let th = scope.spawn(move |_| {
                let mut psum = 0.;
                for _ in 0..10 { psum += self.s; }
                psum
            }); // <--- here, add a ;
            let psum = th.join().unwrap(); //get the inner result
            psum //forward it to the outer scope
        }).unwrap();
        return 0.;
    }
```

Comment: There is one small error in your example with requiring a { stuff } scope after the declaired thread scope. The compiler requires that the let pattern in fubar be compiled with nightly so #![feature(let_chains)] can be used. Doing these two things is a solid answer and I feel like I understand this much better now. I do appreciate the answer buddy, thanks!

Comment: @DaltonTinoco: `{}` added, thanks. But I don't see any `let` pattern or any chance to use `let_chains`.

Comment: please see the updated question for the complete answer. Attempting to take away the nested let will not work and there is a new set of `{}` that get added in line 18,44 of the working example.

Comment: @DaltonTinoco: Sorry but I still do not see the chainet `let`. Your code seems to compile fine without that [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aeaaa76c542e180d90cdf78b71a4fd09).